# Displaying Google AdSense Advertisements only to Facebook, Twitter Visitors

Tags: php, preg-match, adsense, http-referer

I am using below code. When I place this code in `single.php`, it's showing ads *with* content. I want, when a Facebook visitor visits my URL, that it shows *only* ads and no content. When others visitors normally visit the URL, then it should show the content.

```
<?php

    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (preg_match("(facebook)", $ref) != false) {
        echo <<<END
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    /* xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xx xxxxxx */
    google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    google_ad_width = xxx;
    google_ad_height = xxx;
    //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</div>
END;
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }

?>
```

If `single.php` is the wrong place, where should I placed it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
<?php

    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (preg_match('facebook\.com', $ref) != false) {

?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    /* xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xx xxxxxx */
    google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    google_ad_width = xxx;
    google_ad_height = xxx;
    //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</div>
<?php

    } else {
        echo "";
    }

?>
```

Another way you can check the referral is to use `strpos` instead of `preg_match`.

```
<?php

    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (strpos($ref, 'facebook.com') != false) {

?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    /* xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xx xxxxxx */
    google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    google_ad_width = xxx;
    google_ad_height = xxx;
    //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</div>
<?php

    } else {
        echo "";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply,Where i set this code? i mean where i set ( function.php, Single.php, header.php, footer.php ), Where?

Comment: Where i set this code? i mean where i set ( function.php, Single.php, header.php, footer.php ), Where?

Comment: Whereever you want to display the ad. do you want the display the ad in the header? footer? blog posts (single.php).

Comment: i want to display ad in the single.php but one problem, when i display ad single.php and visit url from facebook its show ads + content/post. i want to show only ads, not with content/post.

Comment: Have you tried using the code I provided above? I assumed you did and it worked and thats why you selected it as an answer.

Comment: its works fine but one problem, i want to show only ads, not with content/post. Please post this url on facebook and click on it, then you understand what i say. http://blog.masudtools.com/2016/07/11/javascript-test-post-three/

Comment: Please post this url on facebook and click on it, then you understand, what i say. http://blog.masudtools.com/2016/07/11/javascript-test-post-three

Comment: I dont know how your single.php looks but there should be a line called "the_content()". Move that line into the else statement.